# Why can't I iterate through JSON data in Angular (typescript)?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

```
dataset: any = {
    "days": [
      {
        "datevalue":1,
        "status":"disable",
        "addclass":"notallowed",
        "avability":[]
      },
      {
        "datevalue":2,
        "status":"disable",
        "addclass":"allowed",
        "avability":[]
      }
    ]
}



<tr *ngFor="let row of dataset.days; let i = index">
   <td *ngFor="let day of row | keyvalue">
      {{day.datevalue}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

**How to print the datevalue inside *td* ? Currently its showing blank.**

*I AM STUCK VERY BADLY. PLEASE HELP*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable

Answer (score 3):

row is an object, and you re trying to loop it, it's not possible, you need to use Object.keys: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```
for (let row of this.dataset.days) {
  for (let data of Object.keys(row)) {
    console.log(row[data]);
  }
 }
```

EDIT:
To loop an object through a *ngFor, there is a pipe KeyValuePipe:
https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe

```
<div *ngFor="let item of yourObject | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

in your case :

```
    <tr *ngFor="let row of dataset.days; let i = index"> 
       <td *ngFor="let item of row | keyvalue"> 
           {{ item.value }} 
       </td> 
    </tr>
```

Comment: You might want to link to the *English* version of the documentation for this English oriented site.

Comment: Yes, i didn't pay attention, edited

Comment: How to show in view file?

<tr *ngFor="let row of dataset.days; let i = index">
          <td *ngFor="let data of row">
            {{data}}
          </td>
        </tr>

Comment: I edited, my answer

Comment: @Soukyone how to print datevalue in td?

Comment: My code part, is already with td

Answer (score 0):

While `this.dataset.days` is an array (the outer *for ... of* loop doesn't throw an error), its elements are objects, and you can't iterate through them.

```
for (let row of this.dataset.days) {
  console.log(row);
}
```

Will work.

Comment: <tr *ngFor="let row of dataset.days; let i = index">
          <td *ngFor="let data of row">
            {{data}}
          </td>
        </tr>